# How to use group by and return rows with null values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, missing-data

I have a data set like below on emails and purchases.

```
Email          Purchaser    order_id    amount 
a@gmail.com    a@gmail.com    1         5
b@gmail.com         
c@gmail.com    c@gmail.com    2         10
c@gmail.com    c@gmail.com    3         5
```

I want to find the total number of people in the data set, the number of people who purchased and the total number of orders and total revenue amount. I know how to do it via `SQL` using `left join` and aggregate functions but I do not know how to replicate this using `Python`/`pandas`.

For `Python`, I attempted this using `pandas` and `numpy`:

```
table1 = table.groupby(['Email', 'Purchaser']).agg({'amount': np.sum, 'order_id': 'count'})

table1.agg({'Email': 'count', 'Purchaser': 'count', 'amount': np.sum, 'order_id': 'count'})
```

The problem is - it is only returning the rows with an order (1st row and 3rd) but not the other ones (2nd row)

```
Email          Purchaser      order_id    amount 
a@gmail.com    a@gmail.com    1           5
c@gmail.com    c@gmail.com    2           15
```

The `SQL` query should look like this:

```
SELECT count(Email) as num_ind, count(Purchaser) as num_purchasers, sum(order) as orders , sum(amount) as revenue
    FROM
        (SELECT Email, Purchaser, count(order_id) as order, sum(amount) as amount
        FROM table 1 
        GROUP BY Email, Purchaser) x
```

How can I replicate it in `Python`?

Comment: Is purchaser is 'Na or NaN` ? if yes, you could use 'dropna()' to get the result

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - you can read [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not implemented in pandas now - [see](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3729).

So one awful solution is replace `NaN` to some string and after `agg` replace back to `NaN`:

```
table['Purchaser'] = table['Purchaser'].replace(np.nan, 'dummy')
```

```
print table
         Email    Purchaser  order_id  amount
0  a@gmail.com  a@gmail.com         1       5
1  b@gmail.com          NaN       NaN     NaN
2  c@gmail.com  c@gmail.com         2      10
3  c@gmail.com  c@gmail.com         3       5

table['Purchaser'] = table['Purchaser'].replace(np.nan, 'dummy')
print table
         Email    Purchaser  order_id  amount
0  a@gmail.com  a@gmail.com         1       5
1  b@gmail.com        dummy       NaN     NaN
2  c@gmail.com  c@gmail.com         2      10
3  c@gmail.com  c@gmail.com         3       5

table1 = table.groupby(['Email', 'Purchaser']).agg({'amount': np.sum, 'order_id': 'count'})
print table1
                         order_id  amount
Email       Purchaser                    
a@gmail.com a@gmail.com         1       5
b@gmail.com dummy               0     NaN
c@gmail.com c@gmail.com         2      15

table1 = table1.reset_index()
table1['Purchaser'] = table1['Purchaser'].replace('dummy', np.nan)
print table1
         Email    Purchaser  order_id  amount
0  a@gmail.com  a@gmail.com         1       5
1  b@gmail.com          NaN         0     NaN
2  c@gmail.com  c@gmail.com         2      15
```